# How to create buffer around point having projection 4326

Tags: coordinate-system, buffer, postgis-2.0, latitude-longitude

I am trying to create buffer (in meters) around point(`long lat alt`) which is in projection `4326` with below code. But it is not giving expected output.

```
SELECT ST_AsTEXT(ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromText('POINT(78.385333 17.433293 0)', 4326)),63.763271854));
```

But if i convert point to `geography` it is giving correct result.

```
SELECT ST_AsTEXT(ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromText('POINT(78.385333 17.433293 0)', 4326))::geography,63.763271854));
```

What this `st_buffer` doing with `geography` datatype. Without converting it to geography how can i do that? I am new to postgis.

Answer (score 2):

[The basis for the PostGIS geographic type is a sphere.](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography)

The basis for the PostGIS geometry type is a plane. (same link)

Thus, when you run ST_Buffer on a EPSG:4326 geometry, the output is given in degrees of lat/lon. On the other hand, when you do the same for EPSG:4326 geography, you get result in meters.

What you can do (besides using geography type) is projecting your data into the "better" CRS than EPSG:4326 (i.e. national grid system).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using google maps to collection these long, lats. I think it will give data in 4326 (by default). So you are saying with current projection we cannot use geometry to get required buffer in meters?

Comment: No, with EPSG:4326 geometry you cannot.